# Is Marika the only one unaware of her father's true fate?

Tags: mouretsu-pirates

We learn in the final episodes of Mourestu Pirates that

> Marika's father Gonzaemon is alive, and goes by the name of Steel Beard, an imperial pirate captain of the Parabellum

But we also learn that Ririka, Kane and Misa also knew this secret, because

> Ririka is in the Parabellum crew, Kane switched places with his twin brother, and Misa nonchalantly scolds Kane for the switch.

We can infer that the rest of the crew of the bentenmaru also knew, leaving Marika as the only one in the dark.

Is it so?

Comment: Also by re-reading the question without mouseover, I see that my attempts at avoiding spoilers were futile. Deal with it.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but from what I heard, the last arc of the anime is anime original piece. There is nothing in LNs that would suggest Gonzaemon is alive.